# SQL. How to select something "lower than" ? explained better in topic

Tags: sql

Hope you can help a guy out.

Anyway lets say I have a shop and all my stuff has a weight, and lets say that I in my SQL table has an INT with the different weights and I want to select all the cloth that has a weight below 10? how do i do that? this is how far I get:

SELECT * FROM -//- WHERE weight (your help here I guess?)

Anyway hope that someone can help me out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM -//- WHERE weight < 10
```

Comment: I had to wait like 9 min to be able to do that :P while we wait can you tell me how to select the stuff with weight between 10 and 12? :)

Comment: SELECT * FROM -//- WHERE weight BETWEEN 10 AND 12

Comment: Thanks and now it got clickable :)

Answer (score 0):

weight < 10 (or <= to include 10)

Comment: Thanks mate :D I tried with WHERE weight LIKE < 10 that didn't work :P